# Multiple links that change the source of a video to other videos?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create multiple links that when clicked, will change the source of the video being played on the player.

So far I have something that does ALMOST what I want to achieve:

HTML:

```
<video id="videoclip" width="640" height="480" controls preload="none">
<source id="mp4video" src="myvideo.mp4?dl=1">
</video>

<p><a href="#videoclip" id="videolink1">first video</a></p>
<p><a href="#videoclip" id="videolink2">second video</a></p>
<p><a href="#videoclip" id="videolink3">third video</a></p>
<p><a href="#videoclip" id="videolink4">fourth video</a></p>
```

Javascript:

```
videocontainer = document.getElementById('videoclip');
videosource = document.getElementById('mp4video');
newmp4 = 'newvideo.mp4?dl=1';

videobutton = document.getElementById("videolink1");

videobutton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    videocontainer.pause();
    videosource.setAttribute('src', newmp4);
    videocontainer.load();
    videocontainer.play();
}, false);
```

This works great. The problem is, the way the code is written, it will only allow me to change the first video into the second one and that's it. I want to be able to click the other links (videolink2, videolink3, etc) and change what video is being played to something else.

I already spend many hours looking at many other questions here but wasn't able to achieve my goal.

Comment: Why don't you use multiple video elements and use javascript to change the visibility of them instead of changing the src?

Comment: @JoePi depending on how many videos there are to load at page load it could seriously impact the load time for his users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think dynamic in situations like this. What you did to get one working is a good first stepping stone.

Each video link now has a `data-` attribute that holds the new source for that link.

Each video link also has the same `class` that way we can group them together using `document.getElementsByClassName("videolink")` which returns an array of elements with the classname `videolink`

Then run a loop over the returned array (which is a link element with the classname `videolink`) and add a click event on each one that calls the `changeVideo` function

`this` inside `changeVideo` refers to the element that was clicked. So we grab the `data-videolink` value using `dataset` property on the link element that was just clicked

Finally change the source of the video to that value.

```js
var videocontainer = document.getElementById('videoclip');
var videosource = document.getElementById('mp4video');
var videoButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("videolink");

for (var i = 0; i < videoButtons.length; i++) {
  videoButtons[i].addEventListener("click", changeVideo, false);

}

function changeVideo() {
  var newLink = this.dataset.videolink;
  console.log("Changing video to source: " + newLink);
  //videocontainer.pause();
  //videosource.setAttribute('src', newLink);
  //videocontainer.load();
  //videocontainer.play();
}
```

```html
<video id="videoclip" width="640" height="480" controls preload="none">
<source id="mp4video" src="myvideo.mp4?dl=1">
</video>

<p><a href="#videoclip" data-videolink="newvideo.mp4?dl=1" class="videolink">first video</a></p>
<p><a href="#videoclip" data-videolink="newvideo2.mp4?dl=1" class="videolink">second video</a></p>
<p><a href="#videoclip" data-videolink="newvideo3.mp4?dl=1" class="videolink">third video</a></p>
<p><a href="#videoclip" data-videolink="newvideo4.mp4?dl=1" class="videolink">fourth video</a></p>
```